# Lower bound functional binomial r.v.

Tags: probability, inequality, binomial-coefficients, expectation

I am trying to find a bound of the type

$\mathbb{E}(|B-\frac{N}{2}|) \geq C \sqrt{N}$

Where $B$ is a binomial variable with parameters $(N,\frac{1}{2})$.

The bound doesn't need to be very tight in the constant, however it is important for me that $C$ is explicit. It cannot be just an asymptotic bound. It should be valid for every $N$.

Thanks.

Comment: You are asking for a bound valid for every N. Is there one on the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better than an approximate lower bound, ... one can calculate the desired expectation exactly (and neatly too). In this instance, $X \sim Binomial(n,\frac12)$ with pmf $f(x)$:

[image]

Then, the expectation you seek is:

[image]

Here is a plot of the solution, as parameter $n$ varies:

[image]

**Notes**

1. The `Expect` function used above is from the *mathStatica* package for *Mathematica*. As disclosure, I should add that I am one of the authors.
2. `Ceiling[x]` rounds up to the nearest integer; *e.g.* `Ceiling[2.2]` returns 3.

Comment: This might lead eventually to a constant $C$ valid for every $N\leqslant30$, but not for every $N$.

Comment: thanks; do you have an idea how to find the formula analytically?